# Is the given vector in span(v1,v2)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vectors (in $\mathbb{R}^3$):

$$
v_1=\begin{pmatrix}6\\1\\-3\end{pmatrix},~ v_2=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }
w=\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\1\end{pmatrix} $$

is $w$ in $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$?

I began setting it up to get it in reduced row echelon form but am not quite sure what that gives me.  I am getting $x_1=-11$ and $x_2=5$ when doing that but I don't know if that proves anything or not.

Sorry about the formatting.

Answer (score 4):

The result depends upon the **number of pivots** you have in the RREF.

Notably

- if the pivots are 3 the vectors are linearly independent
- if the pivots are 2 then you can write one as combination of the others two
- if the pivot is 1 then the three vectors are collinear.

In this case

$$\begin{bmatrix}6&1&-3\\-3&3&2\\3&4&1 \end{bmatrix}
\to\begin{bmatrix}6&1&-3\\-3&3&2\\0&7&3 \end{bmatrix}
\to\begin{bmatrix}6&1&-3\\0&7&1\\0&7&3 \end{bmatrix}
\to\begin{bmatrix}6&1&-3\\0&7&1\\0&0&2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore

$$w\not \in span(v_1,v_2)$$

What is in the span is

$$u =\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\-1\end{pmatrix}\quad u=v_1+v_2$$

Comment: Is that the same as the rank of a matrix?  If so, I am getting only 2 rows with a nonzero element.  What exactly would the linear combination look like?

Comment: @DavidStevens Are you sure? the RREF seems to have 3 pivots thus w is not in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B6,+1,+-3%7D,+%7B-3,+3,+2%7D,+%7B3,+4,+1%7D%7D

Answer (score 2):

If $w$ is in span($v_1,v_2$), then we can express $w$ as the linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, that is
$$w = \lambda v_1+\mu v_2 \implies \begin{pmatrix}6\\1\\-3\end{pmatrix} = \lambda\begin{pmatrix}-3\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}\text{+ }
\mu\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\1\end{pmatrix},\ \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$$

From this equation, we have the following equation system:
$$-\lambda+\mu = 2\ (I)$$
$$3\lambda+4\mu = 1\ (II)$$
$$2\lambda+\mu = -3\ (III)$$

Adding up $(II)$ and $(III)$, we have
$$5\lambda+5\mu = -2 \implies \lambda+\mu = -\frac{2}{5}\ (IV)$$

Now, adding up $(I)$ and $(IV)$, we have
$$2\mu = \frac{8}{5} \implies \mu = \frac{4}{5} \implies \lambda = -\frac{6}{5}$$

However, notice that these two values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ doesn't satisfy $(II)$ and $(III)$ so we can say that we can't express $w$ as linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Therefore, $w$ is not in span($v_1,v_2$).

Comment: I couldn't have stated it any better myself.! This is an excellent answer.

Comment: Thank you @WannaBeRealAnalysist :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}6&-3&3\\1&3&4\\-3&2&1 \end{bmatrix}

We can reduce this matrix to row reduced echelon form by the following steps:

$\to$

\begin{bmatrix}3&-1&1\\0&-10&-11\\0&1&2 \end{bmatrix}
$\to$

\begin{bmatrix}3&-1&1\\0&1&\frac{11}{10}\\0&1&2 \end{bmatrix}
$\to$

\begin{bmatrix}3&0&3\\0&1&\frac{11}{10}\\0&1&2 \end{bmatrix}
$\to$

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&\frac{11}{10}\\0&0&\frac{-9}{10} \end{bmatrix}
$\to$

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}

Notice that in RREF, this matrix reduces to the identity matrix. This means our original matrix is rank 3 (full rank). This implies that these three vectors are linearly independent and hence cannot be written as a linear combination of the other vectors.

So to answer your question, $w$ is not in the $span$ of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Hope this helps

Comment: You don't need all this work to reduce to the identity matrix it is sufficient express the RREF in up triangular matrixe in few steps.

Comment: I know. I was just trying to be clear and offer a different solution to those given above.

Answer (score 1):

We can also find the span first, then check whether $w$ satisfies the equation of that subspace or not.

First, we know that span($v_1,v_2$) is the subspace which includes all the vectors that can be obtained by the linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Therefore, we have the equation
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =\lambda\begin{pmatrix}6\\1\\-3\end{pmatrix}+
\mu\begin{pmatrix}-3\\3\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}6\lambda-3\mu\\\lambda+3\mu\\-3\lambda+2\mu\end{pmatrix} ,\ \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$$

From here, we can say that $-11x+3y-21z = 0$ so we can express span as
$$\text{span}(v_1,v_2) = \bigg\{(x,y,z)\ \big|\ z = \frac{-11x+3y}{21}\bigg\}$$
which is an equation for a plane in $3D$-space.

Now, it is easy to see that $x = 3$, $y = 4$, $z = 1$ doesn't satisfy the equation of the plane therefore $w$ is not on that plane, hence not in the $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$.